# Do non-US citizens still have to get an additional TSA check?

Tags: pilot-certification, tsa

I'm familiar with the rules requiring [all non-US citizens to acquire TSA clearance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1587/what-security-clearances-does-a-foreign-citizen-doing-a-flying-course-in-the-uni), but as of 2016 the rules have been changed and it seems that everybody has their background checked by the TSA as part of the [student pilot certificate application process](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2016/january/14/faa-finalizes-rule-on-student-certificates).

Does this mean that non-US citizens no longer have to go through the separate background check, or will they now be checked twice by the TSA?

Comment: This is probably a dupe of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/21589/62). Essentially, nothing has changed for non-US citizens. The change affects US citizens, who now need TSA approval to solo, but not to start flight training.